# Programmatically open router ports via port triggering

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I'm getting many brute force attacks on my home computer which is behind a DSL modem (very old D-Link, has only web interface), so I decided to protect SSH this way:

Every time I want an SSH connection from outside I run a script connecting from my home computer to outside machine which expects SSH connectivity and set up port triggering to open port 22 for that outside machine.

For example I connect from home computer to Napster port and set up port triggering for Napster port to open the port 22 (SSH). This way I will get SSH brutes only in a period of connectivity and not all the day/night

That's all fine but it doesn't work at all. It seems that port triggering does not occur or opens 22 port for some other machine or does not open it at all. Is this possible at all with port triggering? What is the alternative if not?

Comment: Look into Port Knocking

Comment: @user2320464 I'd love to but I have no `knockd` for my DSL modem :)

Comment: Get a real router that can run knockd along with dd-wrt or OpenWrt.

Comment: @JustinAndrusk yes, thank you. This seems most reasonable for me